# Merge [multi-cam] and [multi-camera]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

As far as I am aware, these two tags represent the same thing.

There are four questions that exist with both tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - the are the same thing.

I have merged the two tags. Thanks.

Comment: I would actually argue that they are potentially two different concepts within that tag, but currently they all seem to be mutli-cam.  There's a significant difference however, between the multi-cam editing features in modern NLEs and doing multi-camera (live switched) production.  Non-switched simultaneous camera capture might be another area too.  I'm not sure how we distinguish between those though.  Perhaps this one should be multi-camera-post or something similar... I'm not sure.